# Generate one MVC model to be used in multiple views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to the concepts of MVC and ASP.NET and I'm wondering if there is a possibility to create a object of my model once and use it throughout different views.

I'm writing an application that gets a JSON object through a web service call that contains all the information to populate. The web service call needs an *ID* to create the right JSON object. Since the JSON object is quite large the web service call takes roughly 2 seconds to download the JSON object. When switching views the model is generated (including the download of the JSON object) every time, which adds an enormous overhead.

Generating different view models for different views does not work, since the download is the bottleneck.

Any ideas how to tackle this problem? Can the downloaded JSON string be stored somehow to be used in the different views? Is it possible to only download the JSON object if the *ID* changes?

Regards

Comment: You can store it in the session

Comment: You could use `MemoryCache` to store the model (using the ID as the key) and call a controller method that checks if it exists, and if not then call the service to return it (and add it to `MemoryCache`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines would work:

```
public ActionResult MyView(int someId)
{
    string json = this.GetJson(someId);
    var model = new MyViewModel(json);
    return this.View(model);           
}

private string GetJson(int id)
{
    string cacheKey = "myJsonCacheKey" + id;

    string cachedJson = this.HttpContext.Cache[cacheKey] as string;

    if (cachedJson != null)
        return cachedJson;

    string actualJson = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://whatever");
    this.HttpContext.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, actualJson);

    return actualJson;
}
```

Just 2 points to note:

- Remember to implement the appropriate thread safety mechanism
- You can use any other caching provider instead of `HttpContext.Cache`, the code will be pretty similar

Comment: Thank you very much Holden! This method works and improves the performance of my tool enormously. Great answer.